# qTranslate X in Themeforest Explore theme's header

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

Themeforest theme Explore offers very good options. One is in the theme settings to select in a WPML Language selector to show in header:

Language Switcher On Header Top Show/Hide

header.php

```
if(has_action('wpml_add_language_selector')) {
    $show_laguage_switcher = Slzexploore::get_option('slz-language-switcher');
        if($show_laguage_switcher == '1'){
              echo '<div class="wpml-language">';
                    do_action('wpml_add_language_selector');
                    echo '</div>';
                        }
}
```

Now, 
I want simply to replace with the qTranslateX shortcode, as a function in the child theme. Any ideas?
Any help

Answer (score 0):

Look here in the official documentation (I think 4. is what you search for):

[FAQ - What language switching methods are available at front end?](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/#LanguageSwitchingMethods)